# How to get Selenoid session ID

Tags: selenoid

I would like to clarify how can I use Selenoid API to check downloaded files.
According the documentation to get downloaded file from container I need to call

> http://selenoid-host.example.com:4444/download/f2bcd32b-d932-4cdc-a639-687ab8e4f840/myfile.txt

where **f2bcd32b-d932-4cdc-a639-687ab8e4f840** is a Selenoid Session ID

So, the question is "How can I get this session ID?"
Value, returned by getSessionId from RemoteWebDriver doesn't look like correct one.

**UPD. My bad. Session ID, that I can get from RemoteWebDriver instance, is correct.
The problem was I didn't wait enough to get a file exactly downloaded into container. That's why I got 404 error on attempt to get a file via API**

Answer (score 0):

Thats depends on your client bindings that you use for tests.

For example in java:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

SessionId session = ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getSessionId();
System.out.println("Session id: " + session.toString());
```

If you want to get list of active sessions with their IDs outside of tests: use selenoid /status endpoint

Pleas notice, if you use GGR - it modifies session id -

> every new browser session in Selenium automatically obtains an ID
>   called session ID. According to Selenium JSONWire protocol this ID is
>   always passed to request. GridRouter appends information about
>   selected Selenium Hub to this session and returns enriched session ID
>   to user.

https://hackernoon.com/selenium-testing-a-new-hope-7fa87a501ee9

Comment: At the moment I don't use GGR and I've tried to get session ID by the simple way as you described: SessionId session = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getSessionId();
But I was a bit confused, that the format of session ID string doesn't match the format in documentation, and when I tried to use this value in the endpoint path, I got 404 response, though requested downloaded file was in place. Will try to check /status response.

Comment: @СергейМишанин can you update your question with the steps you are doing and responses you are getting? I'm using Mink with selenoid+ggr and using file download just fine.